# How do I add text under the grid columns in html?

Tags: html, css

How to add text under the column using grid?

[I try to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAUP9.png)

This is my code so far:

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 240px 240px;
  row-gap: 43px;
  column-gap:24px;
}
.grid > div{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
  <div>item1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: put your text inside another div and postion:absolute?

Comment: You have to have additional text divs as well as the structural ones. You need to add those.

Answer (score 2):

I'd combine it with flex. Is that even legal? ;-)

The grey `figure` tag is your image.

```css
 .grid {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
   grid-auto-rows: 240px 240px;
   row-gap: 43px;
   column-gap: 24px;
 }
 figure{
   background:silver;
   display:block;
   width:100%;
   height:200px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }

.inner{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.t{
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="grid">
     <div class="inner">
       <figure></figure>
       <div class="t">
         Text
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="inner">
       <figure></figure>
       <div class="t">
         Text
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="inner">
       <figure></figure>
       <div class="t">
         Text
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="inner">
       <figure></figure>
       <div class="t">
         Text
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="inner">
       <figure></figure>
       <div class="t">
         Text
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```